# Cannot separate expression using stack

Tags: c, stack

I would like to get help for resolving my problem.
I have an expression as char sequence, i want to separate it using stack, i split this expression into every operand and operator, each of them is sequence and i want to push it into stack. The problem is when i try to print expression after separating, only operators display correctly, but operands are not correct. They only display the same operand value as the top element. I don't know why, this is my code, please help me to check it. Thank you so much!

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "malloc.h"
#include "string.h"
#define SIZE 100
typedef struct Stack{
    int top;
    char *data[9];
}Stack;

void init(Stack *s){
    s->top = 0;
}
void push(Stack *s, char *value){
    if(s->top < SIZE)
        s->data[s->top++] = value;
    else
        printf("stack is full");
}

bool isDigit(char s){
    if(s>='0' && s<='9')
        return true;
    return false;
}

void separate(Stack *exp,char *s){

    char temp[9];
    int n = strlen(s);  
    int l = 0,size=0;
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        if(isDigit(s[i])){
            temp[l++]=s[i];

        }
        else{           
            if(l!=0){
                temp[l]='\0';               
                push(exp,temp);
                l=0;    
            }

            char *c= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
            sprintf(c,"%c",s[i]);
            push(exp,c);
        }               
    }
    temp[l]='\0';
    push(exp,temp);

}

void main(){
    Stack *s = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    init(s);
    char expression[100];
    printf("Enter your expression, for exp: 2-33/134+8\n");
    gets(expression);
    separate(s,expression); 
    int size = s->top;
    printf("\nsize = %d",size);
    printf("\nElements of stack are");
    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
        printf("\n %s",s->data[i]);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  Use `#include <stdio.h>` etc with angle brackets rather than double quotes for standard headers (headers provided by the system rather than ones you wrote).  Don't use `#include <malloc.h>` – use `#include <stdlib.h>` instead (as you already do).  The `<malloc.h>` header is only relevant when you want to fettle the behaviour of the memory allocation code and you link with `-lmalloc` to collect the controllable version of the memory allocation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using the same memory location, `temp`, to store all digit sequences. This is also wrong because `temp` is local to the function and any access to the pointer (`&temp[0]`) is undefined outside the `separate` function. Use malloc and strcpy to create a new string and copy temp into it. Then push this new string. Alternatively, you can use `atoi` to create an integer and push it instead of pushing a string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this line

```
push(exp,temp);
```

You are pushing the local variable temp on your stack and then you reuse that same array for the next value. Stack will end up pointing to the same value, the last value. E.g. 11+22+33 will store only 33

Instead allocate `temp` with malloc as well

side note: use `isdigit()` from ctype.h instead of your own.